# Add existing Template to Zabbix host

Tags: zabbix, system-monitoring

Version 3.2.6.

After setting up a new host, I go to the Templates tab > Link new template and add `Template App SSH Service` for example.  I then click Update and I get a green "Host updated" banner.

When going back to the Templates tab, the list is still empty.  How do I add an existing template to a host?

Comment: There is a small button called Add once template has been selected, can you double check you are clicking that before hitting update?

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. I figured that button was for adding another row. Thanks!

Comment: I know only from bitter experience :)

Comment: @g81c, please add that as an answer. I consider that behaviour of Zabbix a bug, especially given that it works differently in various pages. Please consider voting on https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7341 .